# Scheduling multiple jobs with their own Cron expressions with Springboot and Quartz

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have successfully developed a application with SpringBoot and Quartz which executes only a single job using a Cron expression defined for that particular job. My implementation is largely based on the information found in following article.

https://chynten.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/quartz-with-databse-and-spring-4/

There, as you can see, the job triggering is done using a bean which encapsulates the cron expression.

```
@Bean
public Trigger simpleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("simpleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
    factoryBean.setName("test-trigger");
    factoryBean.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now().toDate());
    factoryBean.setCronExpression("0/20 * * * * ?");
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);

    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Now, I am in the need of creating multiple jobs which should be triggered based on their own cron expressions. In above case, the entire project had only one cron, hence I had no issues there.  But now, different jobs should have different schedulings.

How can I extend my current implementation to support multiple jobs with different crons? Yes, I did some research on this, but couldn't find any information on how to configure Spring boot beans to cater my requirement.

Some examples have used quartz `JobBuilder` to define jobs. Is that the way I should follow or can I extend my current implementation to support multiple jobs?

The question in following link looks quite similar, but I cannot understand how to pass different cron expressions and another instructions like misfire instructions to each job separately.

[Autowiring in Quartz multiple Jobs with Spring Boot not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432401/autowiring-in-quartz-multiple-jobs-with-spring-boot-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

you can add multiple triggers separated by comma as argument for `setTriggers`  method in `schedulerFactoryBean()` from example you mentioned method since `setTriggers` accept varagrs of Triggers as argument

```
public void setTriggers(Trigger... triggers)
```

refer [SchedulerFactoryBean API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerAccessor.html#setTriggers-org.quartz.Trigger...-)

you can have different job details for each trigger

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do something like this. Just keep adding new bean for each of your new job

```
    @Bean
public Trigger simpleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("simpleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
    factoryBean.setName("test-trigger");
    factoryBean.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now().toDate());
    factoryBean.setCronExpression("0/20 * * * * ?");
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);

    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean
public Trigger sendSmsJobTrigger(@Qualifier("sendSmsJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
    factoryBean.setName("sms-trigger");
    factoryBean.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now().toDate());
    factoryBean.setCronExpression("0/20 1 1 * * ?");
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);

    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```